# How send a PDF by POST HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, rest, pdf, post, httpwebrequest

(i'm french, sorry for my english)
I don't find / understand how send a simple PDF file by post request at a webService (REST protocol).
I tried some examples but it's doesn't word. And when i use a , it's work, but i want do this in the code behind only !
My question is the title : How send this PDF file?
The url : https://test.website.fr/Website/api/transactions/" + sVal + "/contrat
PDF file : questions.pdf

Thanks.
Iris Touchard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
//Identificate separator
string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
//Encoding
byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

//Creation and specification of the request
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test.website.fr/Website/api/transactions/" + sVal + "/contrat"); //sVal is id for the webService
wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
wr.Method = "POST";
wr.KeepAlive = true;
wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

string sAuthorization = "login:password";//AUTHENTIFICATION BEGIN
byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sAuthorization);
string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
wr.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic " + returnValue); //AUTHENTIFICATION END
Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();


string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}"; //For the POST's format

//Writting of the file
rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Server.MapPath("questions.pdf"));
rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file", "questions.pdf", contentType);
byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("questions.pdf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
fileStream.Close();

byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
rs.Close();
rs = null;

WebResponse wresp = null;
try
{
    //Get the response
    wresp = wr.GetResponse();
    Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
    string responseData = reader2.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string s = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    if (wresp != null)
    {
        wresp.Close();
        wresp = null;
    }
    wr = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Here's a quick code example:

```
        byte[] pdfFile = File.ReadAllBytes("pdf file path here");

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://test.site.fr/Testfile");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = pdfFile.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(pdfFile, 0, pdfFile.Length);
        stream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        reader.Close();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks<br>
But, the webService need more informations : a transfaction id (id = 123456789).
For Information : if i use a <form>, it's working, but, if i do this in c# (code behind), it's doesn't work.<br>
So, how can i add a parameter (id=123465789) at this code ?

Comment: That's not what you were initially asking for. What it sounds like you are asking is that you need to send a pdf document with some supporting information. What type of data is the server requesting? Does it need XML? You should re-word your question to include your full problem.